# Print pages from a .gsp page

Tags: grails

I have a .gsp file where I have 2 forms containing a button for print. I need to print out a page using the information using 2nd form content when print button is pressed.
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to print the HTML page ??

Answer (score 1):

On click of the `print` button, you can populate a hidden `div` with the form information. Then using a CSS print stylesheet (using media queries), you can format that `div` to print the information as you see fit.

If you are looking to popup the print dialog on click, then use `window.print()` in your javascript code.

Comment: Actually I don't want to print the whole page to print. I want to print a small portion or some information from the form contents.